# Proving this trigonmetric identity

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried to prove this identity but I keep getting unhinged by the cubed expression.

$$
\sec(x)(\sin^3(x) + \sin(x)\cos^2(x)) = \tan(x)
$$

I have tried multiplying out the sec, but doesn't really get me anywhere!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sec(x)(\sin^3(x) + \sin(x)\cos^2(x))&=\sec(x)(\sin(x)(1-\cos^2(x)) + \sin(x)\cos^2(x))\\&=\sec(x)\sin(x)\\&=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\sin(x)\\&=\tan(x)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, very helpful to see different ways of solving the problem. - I accepted this answer because it was first.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sec(x)(\sin^3(x) + \sin(x)\cos^2(x)) = \tan(x)$$
$$\frac{(\sin^3(x) + \sin(x)\cos^2(x))}{\cos x} = \tan(x)$$
$$\frac{(\sin(x))(\sin^2x + \cos^2x)}{\cos x} = \tan(x)$$
$$\frac{\sin x\cdot1}{\cos x} = \tan(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove that,

$\sec x(\sin^3 x+\sin x\cos^2 x)=\tan x\\ \implies \sin^2 x\tan x+\sin x\cos x=\tan x\\ \implies \sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$

(Dividing both sides by $\tan x$)

Answer (score 1):

$$\sec  (x)(\sin ^{ 3 } (x)+\sin  (x)\cos ^{ 2 } (x))=\frac { \sin { \left( x \right)  }  }{ \cos { \left( x \right)  }  } \left( \sin ^{ 2 }{ \left( x \right)  } +\cos ^{ 2 }{ \left( x \right)  }  \right) =\tan { \left( x \right)  } $$